# How can I copy certain tables from MSSQL on Windows to Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows

I have a problem - I need to copy few certain tables from MSSQL DB on Windows Server to my Linux machine.
My final goal is to make a backup from Windows, do a few things with it on Linux and then re-create those tables again on another MSSQL DB on Windows.

Is there way to do that with sqlcmd and bcp only? Can BCP, which is running on **Linux**, create a backup of table on **Linux** like pg_dump does it?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I believe this is more appropriate for the dba StackExchange.

Comment: @ewong Hello, thanks! I'll open this question on StackExchange if it is really more appropriate there, sorry for that. Meanwhile, could it be here for a little bit of time? Maybe someone wil provide an answer and there would be no need to post it on another resource.